# Add PostgreSQL to vapor project

Tags: vapor

I added `.package(url: "https://github.com/vapor-community/postgresql-provider.git", .upToNextMajor(from: "2.1.0"))` to my Package.swift file, ran `vapor update` and let it regenerate the Xcode project.  When I then add the import of PostgreSQLProvider Xcode can't find it.  I already have postgresql and pkg-config installed via homebrew.

I'm using Xcode 9 and Swift 4

Comment: `PostgreSQLProvider` also needs to be added to target dependencies in `Package.swift`.  For example:  `.target(name: "App", dependencies: ["Vapor", "FluentProvider", "PostgreSQLProvider"],`

Comment: Thanks.  I'm really struggling getting up to speed on Vapor.  Almost all the tutorials I see are for vapor 1 :(

Comment: "tutorials I see are for vapor 1" … yep, speed bumps.  [Vapor Examples Lab](https://github.com/VaporExamplesLab) was started to work with migrating examples from Vapor 1 to Vapor 2 + Swift 4 (which are not otherwise published as Vapor 2).

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you are using the Swift 4 package manager. The API for it was updated so you have to explicitly add the dependency to the target:

```
// swift-tools-version:4.0

import PackageDescription

let package = Package(
    name: "Project",
    products: [
        .library(name: "App", targets: ["App"]),
        .executable(name: "Run", targets: ["Run"])
    ],
    dependencies: [
        .package(url: "https://github.com/vapor/vapor.git", .upToNextMajor(from: "2.1.0")),
        .package(url: "https://github.com/vapor/fluent-provider.git", .upToNextMajor(from: "1.2.0")),
        .package(url: "https://github.com/vapor-community/postgresql-provider.git", .exact("2.1.0"))
    ],
    targets: [
        .target(name: "App", dependencies: ["Vapor", "FluentProvider", "PostgreSQLProvider"],
                exclude: [
                    "Config",
                    "Public",
                    "Resources",
                ]),
        .target(name: "Run", dependencies: ["App"]),
        .testTarget(name: "AppTests", dependencies: ["App", "Testing"])
    ]
)
```

See above, I added the `PostgreSQLProvider` package to `dependencies` array for `App` target.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem too and wasn't sufficient with vapor xcode because it only regenerate the project and don't fetch the new dependencies like postgree you're adding, to solve this use vapor fetch and later vapor xcode, both commands with the project closed